# Доступ потоков к элементу типа List

Tags: c#, потоки-данных, многопоточность

Всем привет, у меня есть список, и я в него с помощью потоков, создаваемых в цикле записываю значения. Ничего не записывается, я подозреваю, что из-за обращений к элементу типа List.
Код:

```
puplic class MyClass(){

 List<string> list = new List<string>();

public MyClass(){
    FillList();
}

public void FillList(){
for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
   new System.Threading.Thread(delegate() {Do(i);}).Start();

}

}

  void Do(int i){
  list.Add(i);
  }
}
```

Упрощенный пример, повторяет мою реализацию. Подозреваю нужно использовать Lock. Но могу разобраться, как правильно.
Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Не записывается? И не ругается? А где вы проверяете что не записывается?

Comment: у вас код синтаксически неверен

Comment: Не записывается и не ругается, просто виснет.
Я разобрался, нужно использовать тип не List<T>, а, например, BlockingCollection<T>, поскольку второй является потокобезопасным.
Ответьте кто-то на этот пост, ибо у меня низкий рейтинг для этого. 
Спасибо.

Comment: to DreamChild
Возможно, т.к. я писал в спешке, а что именно не так?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Вы не имеете права модифицировать список одновременно из различных потоков. Попробуйте так:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
object mutex = new object();

for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    new Thread(() => Do(i, mutex)).Start();

void Do(int i, object mutex)
{
    // длинные вычисления
    lock(mutex)
        list.Add(i);
}
```

С другой стороны, зачем вам такие низкоуровневые конструкции? Есть гораздо более удобные высокоуровневые средства. Вы можете, например, использовать PLINQ:

```
List<int> list =
    Enumerable.Range(0, 50)
              .AsParallel()
              .AsOrdered()    // если порядок важен
              .Select(Compute)
              .ToList();

int Compute(int i)
{
    // длинные вычисления
    return i;
}
```

Обязательно почитайте: http://www.albahari.com/threading/ (там есть ссылка на русский перевод, но он, кажется, неполный).

Comment: Спасибо, теперь буду знать если что, как записывать в List с помощью lock и mutex!

Comment: @Azastra: дополнил ответ. `BlockingCollection`, конечно, тоже сработает, но зачем вам блокирование при последующем _чтении_ результата?

Comment: @VladD
Спасибо, обязательно прочитаю.
Про PLINQ не задумывался даже. Спасибо за пример.
А почему будет блокироваться при чтении?
Я собираюсь в WPF просто забиндить BlockingCollection к dataGrid.ItemSource.
Может мне следует использовать другую коллекцию из пространства System.Collections.Concurrent?

Comment: @Azastra: Ну, `BlockingCollection` при чтении ведь не знает, что больше никто не пишет? Вот ей и приходится блокироваться самостоятельно. В любом случае, мне кажется, лучше лучше использовать более высокоуровневую семантику: будет понятнее, легче в поддержке, и меньше шанс допустить ошибку.

Comment: Я просто не могу разобраться как параллельно использовать Вашу конструкцию с PLINQ.
Вместо BlockingCollection я пытался записывать в ConcurrentBag с помощью потоков, но не выходит.

Comment: @Azastra: А код как в примере с PLINQ работает как надо? Покажите, что именно вы делаете. Обратите внимание, что функция `Compute` не модифицирует массив сама, она «чистая», занимается _только_ вычислениями.